# Pandas: if row in column A contains "x", write "y" to row in column B

Tags: python, pandas

For `pandas`, I'm looking for a way to write conditional values to each row in column B, based on substrings for corresponding rows in column A.

So if cell in `A` contains `"BULL"`, write `"Long"` to `B`. Or if cell in `A` contains `"BEAR"`, write `"Short"` to `B`.

Desired output:

```
A                  B
"BULL APPLE X5"    "Long"
"BEAR APPLE X5"    "Short"
"BULL APPLE X5"    "Long"
```

B is initially empty: `df = pd.DataFrame([['BULL APPLE X5',''],['BEAR APPLE X5',''],['BULL APPLE X5','']],columns=['A','B'])`

Comment: This is a very good question. The column B desired is Binary what if you have to assign B based on string search.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your code would error as you creating the Dataframe incorrectly, just create a single column `A` then add `B` based on `A`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["BULL","BEAR","BULL"], columns=['A'])
df["B"] = ["Long" if ele  == "BULL" else "Short" for ele in df["A"]]

print(df)

    A      B
0  BULL   Long
1  BEAR  Short
2  BULL   Long
```

Or do you logic with the data before you create the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = ["BULL","BEAR","BULL"]
data2 = ["Long" if ele  == "BULL" else "Short" for ele in data]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(data, data2)), columns=['A','B'])

print(df)
      A      B
 0  BULL   Long
 1  BEAR  Short
 2  BULL   Long
```

For your edit:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['BULL APPLE X5',''],['BEAR APPLE X5',''],['BULL APPLE X5','']], columns=['A','B'])

df["B"] = df["A"].map(lambda x: "Long" if "BULL" in x else "Short" if "BEAR" in x else "")

print(df)

            A      B
0  BULL APPLE X5   Long
1  BEAR APPLE X5  Short
2  BULL APPLE X5   Long
```

Or just add the column after:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['BULL APPLE X5','BEAR APPLE X5','BLL APPLE X5'], columns=['A'])

df["B"] = df["A"].map(lambda x: "Long" if "BULL" in x else "Short" if "BEAR" in x else "")

print(df)
```

Or using contains:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['BULL APPLE X5',''],['BEAR APPLE X5',''],['BULL APPLE X5','']], columns=['A','B'])


df["B"][df['A'].str.contains("BULL")] = "Long"
df["B"][df['A'].str.contains("BEAR")] = "Short"

print(df)
0  BULL APPLE X5   Long
1  BEAR APPLE X5  Short
2  BULL APPLE X5   Long
```

Comment: this only works when not being at Bull you must be a Bear. But this is not exactly the condition of the OP

Comment: @joaquin, the OP does not say there is any other possibility but if there were it would not be too hard to add the logic for it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thank you, I have corrected the OP with the correct DataFrame as to not confuse future readers. You may edit your answer if you like. Will try your solution

Comment: @Winterflags, are there other possibilities beside BULL and BEAR?

Comment: Absolutely, pretty easy to correct. Just I wanted to note that "if cell in A contains "BEAR"" is not the same as " if cell in A doesnt contain "Bull"".

Comment: @PadraicCunningham BULL and BEAR will be the selectors for this particular function, but technically they are embedded in other string content so I will have to use `str.contains` or similar.

Comment: @Winterflags so you are matching substrings?

Comment: Yes, the full value for cell in A may be `BULL APPLE X5` for instance. I should've made more clear that I intended for `contains` although it shouldn't change the fundamentals too much. Sorry about that.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks a lot! Both solutions work beautifully. Is `str.contains` faster than `.map(lambda x:`?

Comment: @Winterflags, I imagine unutbu's might be the fastest but if you can share a link to the data I will run a few tests and see how each performs

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That would probably be too much work to ask of you :) Either one works fine, but `.map(lambda x: ` coincidentally did run a bit jerkily and a .Ds_Store file was created in the folder where I read/write csv to. Not sure what happened there but probably unrelated to the code! Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Winterflags, no prob, I don't mind adding the timings but it is up to yourself.

Answer (score 10):

Also, for populating the `df['B']` you can try the below method -

```
def applyFunc(s):
    if s == 'BULL':
        return 'Long'
    elif s == 'BEAR':
        return 'Short'
    return ''

df['B'] = df['A'].apply(applyFunc)
df
>>
       A      B
0  BULL   Long
1  BEAR  Short
2  BULL   Long
```

What the `apply` function does, is that for each row value of `df['A']` , it calls the `applyFunc` function with the parameter as the value of that row , and the returned value is put into the same row for `df['B']` , what really happens behind the scene is a bit different though, the value is not directly put into `df['B']` but rather a new `Series` is created and at the end, the new Series is assigned to `df['B']` .

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected the OP with the correct DataFrame as to not confuse future readers. You may edit your answer if you like.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html) to search for regex pattern `BULL|BEAR`, and then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to replace those strings with `Long` or `Short`:

```
In [50]: df = pd.DataFrame([['BULL APPLE X5',''],['BEAR APPLE X5',''],['BULL APPLE X5','']],columns=['A','B'])

In [51]: df['B'] = df['A'].str.extract(r'(BULL|BEAR)').map({'BULL':'Long', 'BEAR':'Short'})

In [55]: df
Out[55]: 
               A      B
0  BULL APPLE X5   Long
1  BEAR APPLE X5  Short
2  BULL APPLE X5   Long
```

However, forming the intermediate Series with `str.extract` is quite slow compared to `df['A'].map(lambda x:...)`. Using IPython's `%timeit` to time the benchmarks,

```
In [5]: df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

In [6]: %timeit df['A'].str.extract(r'(BULL|BEAR)').map({'BULL':'Long', 'BEAR':'Short'})
10 loops, best of 3: 39.7 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit df["A"].map(lambda x: "Long" if "BULL" in x else "Short" if "BEAR" in x else "")
100 loops, best of 3: 4.98 ms per loop
```

The majority of time is spent in `str.extract`:

```
In [8]: %timeit df['A'].str.extract(r'(BULL|BEAR)')
10 loops, best of 3: 37.1 ms per loop
```

while the call to `Series.map` is relatively fast:

```
In [9]: x = df['A'].str.extract(r'(BULL|BEAR)')

In [10]: %timeit x.map({'BULL':'Long', 'BEAR':'Short'})
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.82 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, regex is very useful. Will definitely be able to use this.

Comment: Thanks for adding the timeit tests, very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) if you don't mind using *NumPy*:

```
import numpy as np

df['B'] = np.select(
    [df['A'].str.contains('BULL'), df['A'].str.contains('BEAR')],
    ['Long', 'Short'],
    default=np.nan,
)
```

If neither *BULL* or *BEAR* is found, *NaN* is returned.