# Pandas Dataframe: if row in column A, B or C contains “x” or "y", write “z” to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

Very similar to this question: [Pandas: if row in column A contains "x", write "y" to row in column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953299/pandas-if-row-in-column-a-contains-x-write-y-to-row-in-column-b)

I want to know if a row contains "x" or "y" in multiple different columns then output "z" to a new column.

INPUT:

```
A        B        C
Cat      Dog     Pig
Monkey   Tiger   Cat
Cow      Sheep   Goat
```

If "cat" or "tiger" or "lion" - output 1 to new column

OUTPUT

```
A        B        C       CAT FAMILY
Cat      Dog     Pig          1
Monkey   Tiger   Cat          1
Cow      Sheep   Goat         0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `isin` with `any` and `astype`

```
In [298]: cat_family = ["Cat", "Tiger", "Lion"]

In [303]: df['CAT_FAMILY'] = df.isin(cat_family).any(1).astype(int)

In [304]: df
Out[304]:
        A      B     C  CAT_FAMILY
0     Cat    Dog   Pig           1
1  Monkey  Tiger   Cat           1
2     Cow  Sheep  Goat           0
```

Comment: Cheers, very clean